# OS X Service UI

Tags: macos, service

i would like to develop an app like Popclip(https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/popclip/id445189367?mt=12) for Mac OS X. i have done some research and my best guess is that i will need to use a Service(http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html). 
**But how can i make a UI for service?** google search didn't help and only suggest android...

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: You'll have to create a Mac app and communicate with the service somehow.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do, but i don't really know how.

Comment: You don't know how to create a Mac app or you don't know how to communicate with the service?

Comment: don't know how to communicate with the service. I.e. get location of selected text outside of my app and draw my UI over it.

Comment: Selected text would be passed to your application by NSPasteboard automatically here`s [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-SW1)